# Deletion residuals

Tags: r, self-study, residuals

Please can you help me to solve this problem. It should be calculated by vectorization. The question is:

> The i-th deletion residual $e_{(-i)}$ is defined as $e_{(-i)} = y_i - X^\top B_{(-i)}$
>   where $(X^\top)$ is the i-th row of the design matrix $X$ and $B_{(-i)}$ is a column vector of least square parameter estimates calculated without the i-th observation. Write some annotated R code to calculate the deletion residuals when the linear model $y_i = B_0 + B_1 X_i + B_2X_i^2 + E_i$
>   is fitted to the data in the file quadratic.txt. By drawing suitable plot, comment on the distribution of these deletion residuals.

---

**Edit**

I wrote some r codes , but it just gives me residual. I want to calculate deletion residual for i-th cases.

```
> quad<-read.table("quadratic.txt", header=T)
> quad
```

tha data is like this

```
x=(0.75078002, 0.70959645 ,0.07482854,0.60755927 ,0.55037327 ,0.55037327,   
0.35458257 ,0.21994714,0.66369585,0.12381099, 0.12381099,0.12381099,  
0.77869635,0.63917962)
```

and

```
y=(18.715191,17.394049,-2.346149,5.528978,6.765831,6.324425,13.803874,  
15.007047,4.034973,12.383765,14.823395)

> quad.lm<-lm(y~x+I(x^2), data=quad)
> resid(quad.lm)
        1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
3.7933593  3.2646946 -4.9080046 -6.6589585 -4.3477835 -1.1856694  8.7046506 
        8          9         10         11 
1.7549092  0.6237708 -3.0781575  2.0371889
```

Comment: Since this is homework, can you explain what work you've done so far or what part of the problem is giving you trouble? We prefer not to just solve your homework for you, since then you don't learn very much...

Comment: I added the 'homework' tag, but you should feel free to explain how this arises in a way that doesn't come under the tag if you think it doesn't belong.

Comment: Actually I am not good in R because I have not used it before. So I just need some explanation about vectorization in order to start it. Thank you so much

Comment: I have merged your two accounts, nina. You'll still need to [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) to benefit from all Stack Exchange facilities (notifications, comments, update, etc.).

Comment: you can get studentized deleted residuals via `rstudent` or `MASS::stdres` (`?rstudent` or `?MASS::stdres` to see the help on them) - if you want *raw* deleted residuals you'd need to compute them directly or from the standardized versions

Comment: **This question should not be responded to, this is an assigned question in a degree programme.**

Comment: @nina If there is a serious problem with this question, please flag it for deletion instead of replacing it by $11111111111...$ These changes can be rolledback, anyway.

Answer (score 8):

This kind of jackknifing problem can be programmed straightforwardly, but that usually results in a tangle of `for` loops. Some linear algebraic manipulations go a long way in drastically reducing code length (if your computer's memory can handle it).

---

- Consider the original regression equation
  $$
  Y_i= \boldsymbol{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta} + \varepsilon_i;\;i=1, \ldots, n
  $$
  where $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ is a $k\times 1$ vector of regressors.You can write this more compactly as
  $$
  \boldsymbol{Y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
  $$
- Then the model that you want to estimate can be stacked up as
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{Y}^{(-1)} \\
  \vdots \\
  \boldsymbol{Y}^{(-n)} \\
  \end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{X}^{(-1)} & & \\
   & \ddots & \\
   & & \mathbf{X}^{(-n)}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\beta}^{(-1)} \\
  \vdots \\
  \boldsymbol{\beta}^{(-n)} \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\equiv \boldsymbol{\beta}^-}
  +
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^{(-1)} \\
  \vdots \\
  \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}^{(-n)} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  where $\boldsymbol{Y}^{(-i)} = [Y_1, \ldots, Y_{i-1}, Y_{i+1}, \ldots, Y_n]'$ is the $n-1 \times 1 $ vector with the $i$-th row (of $\boldsymbol{Y}$) deleted; and $\mathbf{X}^{(-i)} = [\boldsymbol{X}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{X}_{i-1}, \boldsymbol{X}_{i+1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol{X}_n]'$ is the $(n-1)\times k$ matrix with the $i$-th row (of $\mathbf{X}$) deleted. Note that the design matrix in this regression equation is block diagonal. Also, this is a very large system.
- Once $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^-$ in the system above is estimated (by least squares), the residuals you want to estimate ($Y_i - \boldsymbol{X}_i'\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{(-i)}$) can be had simply as $\boldsymbol{Y} - \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{X}\mathrm{ivec}(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^-))$, where the $\mathrm{diag}$ operator extracts the diagonal and $\mathrm{ivec}$ is the inverse of the  $\mathrm{vec}$ operator which stacks the columns of the matrix.

---

### R code

Here is some R code to show how this can be done. The only trick here is constructing the stacked, row-deleted matrices, and then you are left with one (very) large least squares problem to solve.

```
iN <- 50                # number of observations
iK <- 4                 # number of regressors (including constant)

mX <- matrix(rnorm(iN*iK), nrow = iN, ncol = iK)  # design matrix
vBeta <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)                            # coefficients
vY <- mX%*%vBeta + matrix(rnorm(iN))              # dependent variable
mXStacked <- (diag(iN)%x%mX)[-seq(from = 1, 
                                    to = iN*iN, by = iN+1), ]  # Stacked design matrix
vYStacked <- vec(vY%*%t(rep(1, iN)))[-seq(from = 1, 
                                            to = iN*iN, by = iN+1), ]   # Stacked outcomes
vBetaMinus <- solve(t(mXStacked)%*% mXStacked, 
                    t(mXStacked)%*%vYStacked)           # estimated coefficients
mBetaMinus <- matrix(vBetaMinus, nrow = iK, ncol = iN)
vResid <- vY - diag(mX%*%mBetaMinus)                  # required residuals

matplot(vResid, type = "l")           # plot the estimated residuals
```

#### Given dataset

The above R code can be easily adapted to the given dataset. Your outcome vector appears to be shorter than the regressor vector, so I have clipped off some of the latter.

```
vY <- as.matrix(c(18.715191,17.394049,-2.346149,5.528978,6.765831,6.324425,13.803874,  
   15.007047,4.034973,12.383765,14.823395))
x <- c(0.75078002, 0.70959645 ,0.07482854,0.60755927 ,0.55037327 ,0.55037327,   
   0.35458257 ,0.21994714,0.66369585,0.12381099, 0.12381099) 
mX <- as.matrix(cbind(constant = 1, x = x, x2 = x^2))
iN <- nrow(mX)
iK <- ncol(mX)
mXStacked <- (diag(iN)%x%mX)[-seq(from = 1, 
                                    to = iN*iN, by = iN+1), ]  # Stacked design matrix
vYStacked <- vec(vY%*%t(rep(1, iN)))[-seq(from = 1, 
                                            to = iN*iN, by = iN+1), ]   # Stacked outcomes
vBetaMinus <- solve(t(mXStacked)%*% mXStacked, 
                    t(mXStacked)%*%vYStacked)           # estimated coefficients
mBetaMinus <- matrix(vBetaMinus, nrow = iK, ncol = iN)
vResid <- vY - diag(mX%*%mBetaMinus)                  # required residuals

matplot(vResid, type = "l", xlab = "Obs. index", ylab = "Residuals")           # plot the estimated residuals
```

This produces the following picture.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it was great. Well done.but this command (vYStacked) does not work in my r, please can you tell me what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: @nina You will need to install and load the `Matrix` and the `matrixcalc` libraries using `install.packages("matrixcalc")` and `library(matrixcalc)` (similarly for `Matrix`) before you run this code.

Comment: Theank you @Peter. Now it is working. Thank you once again.@Nina

Comment: May I asked why you offered to delete all this reply with your suggested edit, @nina?

Comment: @chl Something bizarre just happened. Thanks for saving my answer. :)

Comment: Please can you explain ( e_(-i)=y_i-X_i^(transpode)*B_(-i) in R code how did you do that? and is that ok if all residuals were positive? Thank you . @Nina

Comment: @nina Firstly, there was a small error in the code that I have now fixed. Secondly, I realise that this answer is probably not easy for an R novice, but it does exactly what you would like, except that it does it in a compact way. The steps are exactly as in the mathematical description above the code.

Comment: thank you so much. by fixing this code the residual has changed. I will appreciate your job thank you.

Comment: I think these deletion residuals have approximate t distribution. I am not quite sure that is correct or no?

Comment: @nina Yes, jackknife residuals are supposed to be distributed $t$ with $n-k-1$ degrees of freedom, where $n$ is the (full) sample size and $k$ is the number of regressors. See for example, [page 297 in Kleinbaum, Kupper, Nizam & Muller (2007)](http://books.google.com/books?id=LnYGgaLQ3MMC&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=Jackknife+residuals+kleinbaum&source=bl&ots=AEGV_1ZQkM&sig=YEH3dcR16NB1AamOdqQhvCWzXLA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1Iy_UJTbIYrZrQfagYHIAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Jackknife%20residuals%20kleinbaum&f=false).

Comment: @nina If you had more observations, I would recommend that you created a kernel density plot and overlaid the PDF of a t-distribution with $n-k-1$ degrees of freedom to illustrate this point, but that might be tough with only 11 observations.